# Why I'm not following conventions for register-saving in an exception handler?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, interrupt-handling

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625593/assembly-change-causes-panic-in-linux-kernel) I posted this code (x86-64 att) in assembly which replaces the handler for invalid opcodes (or may call the previous one if `what_to_do` function returned 0):

```
.globl my_ili_handler

.text
.align 4, 0x90

my_ili_handler:

    movq (%rsp), %r8 # loading %rip from stack
    movb (%r8), %dil # reading first byte in the invalid opcode
    cmpb $0x0F, %dil
    jne function_call
    movb 1(%r8), %dil # else read the 2nd byte instead
    addq $1, %r8
    
function_call:
    addq $1, %r8
    pushq %rbp # save old %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp # move %rbp to top
    # %rax, %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9, %r10, %r11 caller saved.
    subq $8, %rsp
    pushq %r8 # backup %r8
    call what_to_do # unsigned int what_to_do(unsigned char magic)
    popq %r8 # restore %r8
    leave # push return address and jump
    
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je old_handler
    mov %eax, %edi # zero the upper part of %rdi
    addq $8, %rsp # pop old %rip from stack
    pushq %r8
    jmp end

old_handler:
    jmp *old_ili_handler(%rip)

end:
    iretq # go back to user space
```

many of you pointer that I am not following the guidelines regarding saving r8 and rdx but I just don't get it why is that?

But:

1. those registers are caller save, I am saving them before calling `funciton_call` and loading them again so what's the problem with that?
2. I don't need to save them before calling jmp that's not a function call...

plus how am I supposed to fix that without destroying my whole code?

---

First Edit:

```
.globl my_ili_handler

.text
.align 4, 0x90

my_ili_handler:

    movq (%rsp), %r8 # loading %rip from stack
    movb (%r8), %dil # reading first byte in the invalid opcode
    cmpb $0x0F, %dil
    jne function_call
    movb 1(%r8), %dil # else read the 2nd byte instead
    addq $1, %r8
    
function_call:
    addq $1, %r8
    pushq %rbp # save old %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp # move %rbp to top
    # %rax, %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9, %r10, %r11 caller saved.
    subq $72, %rsp
    
    # backup all caller-saved registers
    pushq %rax
    pushq %rdi
    pushq %rsi
    pushq %rdx
    pushq %rcx
    pushq %r8
    pushq %r9
    pushq %r10
    pushq %r11
    
    call what_to_do # unsigned int what_to_do(unsigned char magic)
    
    # restore all caller-saved registers
    popq %r11
    popq %r10
    popq %r9
    popq %r8
    popq %rcx
    popq %rdx
    popq %rsi
    popq %rdi
    popq %rax
    
    leave # (mov %rbp, %rsp) & (pop %rbp) 
    
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je old_handler
    mov %eax, %edi # zero the upper part of %rdi
    addq $8, %rsp # pop old %rip from stack
    pushq %r8
    jmp end

old_handler:
    jmp *old_ili_handler(%rip)

end:
    iretq # go back to user space
```

Comment: Your code would be nicer to read if the label didn't have a spelling error in the word "function", especially since you now reference the label name in another instruction :/

Comment: You're writing an *exception handler*, not an ordinary function!  The code that transferred control to you didn't call you voluntarily, and it's not expecting *any* registers to be modified.  So you must preserve *all* registers, flags, and other relevant CPU state, including those which would be "caller saved" in a normal function call.  Normal calling conventions don't apply because the "caller" isn't cooperating with them.

Comment: But that doesn't answer when I should back them and when to restore them, plus should I back up every other register ? (I know that cmp affects one register should I back it up too? )

Comment: Your edit make the code in the question nonsensical (since nothing sets R8), and invalidates my answer, since you're no longer calling a C function at all.  Rolling it back.  I don't see how that change can be described as "fixing" the code, since it still modifies R8 without saving it.  If you were trying to write an answer, post it as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your interrupt handler isn't a function.  The entire incoming state of registers (except RSP and RFLAGS) belongs to user-space.

`jmp *old_ili_handler(%rip)` is eventually going to record the state of user-space when the fault happened, so you want to avoid distorting user-space state seen by a signal handler or core dump.

**You can look at all registers are "arguments" to the tailcall of the old handler.**  (It's also an interrupt handler, not a function, so you `jmp` to it with stack/registers in a state that matches the state on entry to your handler, so it works as if it was invoked directly from a fault in user-space.)

Note the similarity with a function like `int foo(int x){return bar(x);}`, which would compile to `jmp bar` instead of `call bar` / `ret`.  i.e. an optimized tailcall that just leaves args in registers. But again, for an exception handler that can either return, deliver a signal, or trigger a core-dump, the entire user-space state in all registers is effectively an argument.

---

In general for other faults, like page-fault, that can resume user-space after fixing the problem, it's even more critical not to corrupt registers: instead of just getting wrong info into core dumps (or breaking the occasional program that emulates missing instructions via a SIGILL handler), you'll break code that does `add (%r8), %edi` if the eventual return to user-space has different register values.  In fact, your code now sometimes jumps to `iret` so you're directly returning to user-space to retry the faulting instruction, perhaps after fixing it, so you *do* have this problem.

Note that **you should actually be saving/restoring all the call-clobbered registers around your `call what_to_do`**, since it's a *function* that follows the C calling convention.

---

e.g. safe code might look like this.  (*untested*).  It would probably make more sense to pass RIP to `what_to_do` and let it return the new RIP, or `0` to run the old handler. (As a bonus, then you don't need to save any extra state across that function call, just the user-space state.)

x86 instructions have a variable number of bytes after the opcode, depending on addressing mode and immediate, so it doesn't make sense to just increment the user-space RIP by 1 or 2.  Or if the 1st byte was actually a prefix like `rep` or `rex`...

You can have illegal instructions that are longer than 2 bytes, like an `lea` encoded with a register source for example (REX + opcode + modrm).  Or a `66 66 0F 0B` (2 prefixes in front of UD2).  So it might be possible to confuse your function when it only looks at 1 byte.

But anyway, I kept your primitive instruction-length decoding to show using a call-preserved register to remember something across the call, separate from saving user-space's state.

```
.globl my_ili_handler
.text
.p2align 4
my_ili_handler:
    push   %rbx    # save a call-preserved reg for our own use

    # %rax, %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9, %r10, %r11 are call-clobbered
    push   %rax
    push   %rcx
    push   %rdx
    push   %rsi
    push   %rdi
    push   %r8
    push   %r9
    push   %r10
    push   %r11

    mov   10*8(%rsp), %rbx   # loading user-space fault address from exception frame
                          # note the n*8(%rsp) since this is after n pushes; same address as (%rsp) on entry.

    movzbl (%rbx), %edi   # byte load of the invalid opcode
    inc    %rbx
    cmp    $0x0F, %edi    # check for 2-byte opcode escape byte
    jne function_call
    inc    %rbx
    movzbl (%rbx), %edi   # else read the 2nd byte instead
    
function_call:
   # RBX points to fault-address + 1 or 2 depending on seeing 0F.
   # Very primitive instruction-length decoding that ignores prefixes
   # and illegal forms of longer instructions with ModRM and/or immediate operands

    # subq $8, %rsp        # 16-byte stack alignment probably not needed in kernel, and I didn't check what the initial alignment was on entry vs. the number of pushes
    cld                    # C calling convention requires DF=0, user-space might have left DF=1
       # 64-bit mode can I think avoid worrying about DS and ES settings
    call what_to_do        # unsigned int what_to_do(unsigned char magic)
    
    cmpl $0, %eax
# now restore everything, before we either 
# run the old handler transparently  or  return to user-space with its regs unchanged

    pop   %r11
    pop   %r10
    pop   %r9
    pop   %r8

    pop   %rdi
    pop   %rsi
    pop   %rdx
    pop   %rcx
    pop   %rax

    je  run_old_handler
end:
    # mov %eax, %edi        # zero the upper part of %rdi.
         #  IDK what this was for.  Is user-space supposed to get this return value?
         # If so, only restore RAX in the other path instead of before the branch
         # and   add $8, %rsp   here instead.

    mov   %rbx, 8(%rsp)     # set the user-space RIP
    pop   %rbx              # restore our call-preserved register
    iretq                   # and return to user-space at the updated RIP
    
run_old_handler:
    pop   %rbx             # just restore RBX
    jmp *old_ili_handler(%rip)   # and run the old handler with all registers in identical state to entry to this handler.
```

Comment: I don't get it yet... I already did  saving/restoring all the call-clobbered registers around call what_to_do. so again what's the problem?

Comment: @john: What would happen if an interrupt service routing (e.g. for a network card) set RAX to 123 every time it ran, asynchronously between any two instructions in whatever it interrupted?  Obviously bad, right?  This is what your exception handler is doing, except only when invoked by illegal instructions.

Comment: @john: Also, it's RDI, not RDX, that holds the first arg.  You're loading into DIL, not DL.

Comment: So from what you said I should back up every single caller saved register before calling what_to_do too since it may change anyone of them and I don't want that to happen? that doesn't sound correct to me...

Comment: To sum things up, you are telling me to do the following: 1) at the start of the function backup ALL caller saved registers and restore them (before or after?) old_handler? 2) back them up Again before what_to_do and load them again after the call is ended? that will turn my code to hundreds of lines easily...

Comment: @john: That is correct, that's what interrupt handlers have to do before calling C functions.  Look at how Linux's `common_interrupt:` entry point uses `SAVE_ALL` which expands (for 32-bit mode) to `cld` / `push %es` / `push %ds` / `pushl %eax` / ...  according to this online excerpt from ["Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s06.html).  I think that's excessive, call-preserved registers like RBX shouldn't need saving if you're not building a `struct pt_regs` for a `task_struct`.

Comment: @john: Save the call-clobbered integer regs (RAX..RDI, R8..R11) and run `cld` on entry to your exception handler.  Restore them once as you're getting ready to leave:  after `cmp` but before `jcc` to decide whether to `iret` or `jmp *old_ili_handler(%rip)`

Comment: But again you didn't answer me in both times when should I load them back again?

Comment: Ok I am 1000% confused now

Comment: @john: I added an example that I think is safe.  It has a total of 10 pushes that always run, and 9 pops that always run.  Only `pop %rbx` is repeated in each path out of the handler.  I simplified / optimized some of your code; it's really not bad.

Comment: Can you take a look after my first edit? I just pushed the registers to the stack and my code doesn't run well (rpi has wrong value at the end) what is causing this? I only pushed and popped more registers...

Comment: @john: IDK, run it in a debugger (like BOCHS), and see what happens.  You're still defeating the purpose by not saving until after `movq (%rsp), %r8` and so on mess up user-spaces R8 and RDI.  The RBP-setup / `leave` is unnecessary (except possibly for backtraces?), as is `sub $72, %rsp`, but the `leave` undoes that 72-byte stack allocation.  Also note that `addq $8, %rsp` / `pushq %r8` is just a clunky way to write `mov %r8, (%rsp)`.

Comment: I can't use debugger as it's calling c functions, it's complicated. Plus, I didn't get it what is the problem with my new code now? I tried to remove sub $72, %rsp but same problem

Comment: Calling C functions doesn't stop you from using an asm-level debugger.  Especially not if you make use a dummy C function that just always returns 0 to test that path.  Anyway, I didn't see any problems (other than losing user-space's registers on #UD), so I don't know what's wrong either - everything I pointed out is just inefficiency, and shouldn't stop it from working.  That's why you should use a debugger to investigate and find more symptoms.

Comment: I am about to lose my mind nothing works for me

Comment: I didn't understand your code and don't want to use cld either

Comment: @john: If you don't want to use `cld` to set DF=0, then be prepared for user-space to be able to crash or maybe exploit your code by doing `std` / `ud2`.  Compiler-generated code assumes that DF=0, so you have to make sure that's true as part of following the calling convention.  You can leave it out if you don't care about robust code and just want a toy experiment.  (Writing secure kernel code is non-trivial :/)

Comment: Wow, I admire your patience Peter! :)